# CORS error with window.fetch on YouTube resource

Tags: javascript, youtube, cors, oembed, fetch-api

I'm using window.fetch to retrieve a YouTube resource with the following URL:

http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[id]&format=json

Using Fiddler, I see that I am getting the expected reply from YouTube's servers containing JSON data. However, I'm not able to use it as I'm getting a Javascript error.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:60366' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I tried enabling CORS on my window.fetch but I read that this will only work if the server allows CORS in its header response. YouTube doesn't have this header field in its reply.

How do I enable my script to accept a response from YouTube using window.fetch? (I'm using Chrome v44.)

```
window.fetch(
            url, {
                method: 'GET',
                mode: 'cors',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'text/plain',
                    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
                }
            })
...
```

Comment: UPDATE: I instead had my server make the YouTube call, and the JavaScript client calls my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use youtube API to be able to make CORS request.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/